# Do I need to startLocationUpdates when registering for regions ios?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

In my app I have registered some CLRegions. My whole functionality lies in these functions:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Entered Region - %@", region.identifier);
    [self showRegionAlert:@"Entering Region" forRegion:region.identifier];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Exited Region - %@", region.identifier);
    [self showRegionAlert:@"Exiting Region" forRegion:region.identifier];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Started monitoring %@ region", region.identifier);
}
```

This function exists in my code, but I do not do anything inside here:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Location Update:%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
}
```

My question is this:

Is this initialisation necessary?

```
- (void)initializeLocationUpdates {
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

when you only want to account for regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you do have to call `startMonitoringForRegion:` for each of the regions you want to monitor. Like this:

```
CLRegion *region = // Set up your region
self.locationManager.delegate = self; // Make sure you are set as the location manager's delegate
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion: region]; // Start monitoring the region
```

See the `startMonitoringForRegion:` doc on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3a)

Comment: Yes, I have done that, I just wasn't sure if I needed to call that either. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I found the docs sometimes don't explain things too clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in being notified when entering / leaving regions, it is sufficient to invoke `startMonitoringForRegion:`. Check out *Staying on Track with Location Services* ([WWDC 2012 Session 303](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_303__staying_on_track_with_location_services.pdf) (Developer Account needed to sign in)).

It might be worth noting that you can monitor 20 regions at most - as stated in the [API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#jumpTo_28).